# Angular component interaction two-way binding approaches

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and trying to understand the possibilities.

To achieve 2-way binding between Angular components for interactions, I have come up with the following possibilities. Is it feasible to use options 5 and 6 as they are not mentioned in the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

1. Event binding + Interaction via child tag level template variable (allows access to child variables from parent template only, and not in component)
2. Event binding + Interaction via @ViewChild() (this allows access to child variables from parent component)
3. Via service
4. Event Binding + Property binding
5. Banana syntax approach (code mentioned below)
6. ngModel

```html
     <childcomponent ([ipVar])="ParentVar">
```

Answer (score 2):

In your child component you have to implement two-way binding interface like this:

```
private _ipVar: any;
get ipVar(): any {
    return this._ipVar;
}
@Input()
set ipVar(value: any) {
    if(this._ipVar === value) {
        return;
    }
    this._ipVar = value;
    this.ipVarChange.emit(this._ipVar);
}
@Output()
ipVarChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

It's mandatory to name `@Output` filed by adding word `Change` to `@Input` name.
So you can use it in your parent component temlate like this:

```
<childcomponent [(ipVar)]="ParentVar"></childcomponent>
```